# Don't somebody sure

Tags: phrases, linguistics

I came across the phrase:

> "don't somebody sure"

and would like help describing its grammar.  The whole sentence is:

> "Yeah, that's right," somebody else would say, "you better hold on to little Miss Bright-eyes, don't somebody sure going to take her away from you."[1](https://books.google.com/books?id=8RYwAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT164&lpg=PT164&dq=don%27t%20somebody%20sure%20tell%20it%20on%20the%20mountain&source=bl&ots=lgWHe8HLet&sig=TePHdZ69IWIc7V2AQoJVeTJDDC4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_7Nnt153NAhUOVFIKHW4GCiIQ6AEIHzAA#v=onepage&q=don't%20somebody%20sure%20tell%20it%20on%20the%20mountain&f=false)

The meaning's clear--"or else somebody is"--but I'm curious if this phrase represents a type of linguistic construction.  Are there any analogous phrases which are formed similarly?

Comment: I would be tempted to add a little punctuation to that sentence to clarify how the grammar is being used. There is some conversational deletion going on, and maybe some other mechanisms. "You better hold on to [her] -- don't, somebody sure going to take her away from you". Note the addition of the emdash to introduce a new clause, and the comma to offset the ", somebody sure" part. Now, it's easier to see what has been omitted: "You better hold on to little Miss Bright-eyes, [if you] don't [then] someonebody [is] sure going to take her away from you".

Comment: This is written dialog attempting to describe a nonstandard English dialect. It's probably not exact; the writer was trying to evoke a scene, not necessarily to make sense or speak correctly. In other words, don't worry if you don't understand it.

Comment: I don't think so, @DanBron: I can imagine hearing it, and I don't hear a comma after "don't".  It looks to me as if "don't" has somehow become grammaticalised into a conjunction meaning "lest" in that dialect. Interesting.

Comment: This is African American Vernacular English (aka Ebonics), which has many ideosyncratic verb uses.

Comment: I've found another example: "Stay out of trouble, I guess, tend to your own business, don't somebody gonna kill you now, " [source](http://www.ibtimes.com/veterans-day-2013-who-richard-overton-meet-oldest-living-us-military-vet-who-credits-longevity)

Comment: @ColinFine I'm pretty sure Dan Bron's right: in my Southern US dialect (as well as AAVE) the contrast of *don't* with the prior mandative licenses the deletion of *if you*. Prof. Lawler can tell us whether this should be categorized as  a true conversational deletion. It's not uncommon for a bare clause, without an *if* or *when*, to be employed as protasis: "The enemy advances, we retreat; the enemy camps, we harass; the enemy tires, we attack; the enemy retreats, we pursue."

Answer (score 2):

I read this as, "[if you] don't, somebody is sure[ly] going to to take her away from you."

The word "sure" used as an adverb to "going"; the basic meaning is unchanged if you omit it.

Therefore, "don't somebody sure" isn't a phrase with a meaning in its own right, as illustrated by Colin Fine's example in the comments, above.